# ListView setSelection apply animation

Tags: android, listview

I have got ListView and TextView, on click TextView which has numbers (for example 3) when i click number 3

```
 list.setSelection(3)
```

it will goes to position 3, its possible to apply animation on position 3? for example flashing 2-3 times or any other animation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, follow this approach:
set onItemSelectedListener
in that you will get View
simple do this

```
view.startanimation(/*your animation*/);
```

hope it will do your job.